# Multi-layer Plot in plolty

Tags: python, plotly

Can we plot another layer of plot over a visualization using plotly through python.?

I am trying to join two points over a bubble chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be aware of the concept of traces, where we can place two types of charts in the same graph. To see the concept in action refer [Multiple Chart Types in Same Graph](https://plot.ly/python/graphing-multiple-chart-types/). Just as a starting point please refer the below code snippet which does what you want.

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from datetime import datetime
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[10, 11, 12, 13],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=[40, 60, 80, 100],
    )
)
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    y = [10, 11, 12, 13],
    line = dict(
        color = ('rgb(22, 96, 167)'),
        width = 4,
        dash = 'line')
)

data = [trace0, trace1]
iplot(data, filename='bubblechart-size')
```

The line that you require can also be generated using plotly shapes. Please read more about this [here](https://plot.ly/python/shapes/)